# tableDnD - Jquery Conflicting With Different Versions

Tags: jquery

I am running into a conflicting issue with multiple Jquery Versions.

I have this plug-in using for drap and drop the table rows, then save the sorting, and it has been working very good.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/RowDragable/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/RowDragable/js/jquery.tablednd.0.7.min.js"></script>


// The code below.
    $('#mytable').tableDnD({
            onDragClass: "myDragClass",
            onDrop: function(table, row) {
                $.post('updateSorting.asp?', {
                    pagesid : "1",
                    arr : $.tableDnD.serialize()

                });

            }
        });
```

Now, I want to include the new version of Jquery (below) and it is conflicting with the version that is using for the "tableDnD".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/jquery/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/Jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/Jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?  Please advise.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Tried that and no luck.  Getting this error when I included the NoConflict. TypeError: $(...).tableDnD is not a function

Comment: Does anyone have other suggestion to solve this?